# Query to count sibling rows given ID of one SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

if I have a table, Tasks with the following sample rows

```
ID  ParentID    Status
1   101     Pending
2   101     Complete
3   101     Complete
4   102     Complete
```

Given ID =2, how can I get number of tasks not complete that belong to same parent?
e.g.

```
Select Count(ID) from Tasks where Status <> ‘Complete’ and ID =2
```

above query does return correct results

Note, I do not want to do
Select Count(ID) from Tasks where Status <> ‘Complete’ and ParentID=101
i.e. I do not want to pass parentID in query, just ID of one of the records that belong to same parent.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a subquery:

```
Select Count(t.ID)
from Tasks t
where t.Status <> 'Complete' and
      t.ParentId = (select t2.parentId from Tasks t2 where t2.ID = 2);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it with 'where t2.ID = 2' outside of the subquery?

Comment: @BillAnderson . . . What is the problem with the condition in the subquery?

Answer (score 0):

The following query uses a sub-query to do the count of sibling tasks (with commented code to exclude the "start point")

```
select 
  ParentId, 
  Status, 
  (select count(*) from Tasks t2 where t2.ParentId = t.ParentId and Status <> 'Complete' 
    --  and t2.Id <> t.Id 
  ) as SiblingTaskCount
from Tasks t
Where t.Id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
declare @t table(ID int,ParentID int,[Status] varchar(50))
insert @t values
(1,101,'Pending')
,(2,101,'Complete')
,(3,101,'Complete')
,(4,102,'Complete')
declare @id int=2
select *
from @t A
inner join
@t B on a.ParentID=b.ParentID
where b.id=@id
and a.Status='Pending'

--OR

;With CTE as
(
select id,parentid,[Status],1 rn from @t where id=@id
union all
select a.id,a.ParentID,a.[Status],
rn+1
from @t A
inner join cte b
on a.ParentID=b.ParentID
where a.id<>@id 
and a.[Status]='Pending'
and b.rn<2

)

select * from cte
where rn>1
```